# Understanding enable_if implementation in C++98

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I have seen this given as a self-explanatory implementation of `enable_if` for `C++98` :

```cpp
template<bool b, typename T = void>
struct enable_if {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false, T> {};
```

But alas I personally don't understand it. I don't see where the boolean kicks into play. Would really appreciate if someone would unwrap it for me.

Comment: do you understand partial template specialization? Its just that

Comment: Notice for the partial specialization that the `typedef` is missing?

Comment: The boolean kicks in when you use it.  In  `enable_if<is_same_v<T, U>>` the  `is_same_v<T, U>` will resolve to true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider this:

```
template<bool b>
struct foo {
    static const bool B = b;
};

template <>
struct foo<false> {
    static const bool B = false;
};
```

Its a primary template and a specialization. In the general case `foo<b>::B` is just `b`. In the special case when `b == false` the specialization kicks in and `foo<false>::B` is `false`.

Your example of `std::enable_if` is different for two reasons: A) It is using partial specialization. The specialization is for any type `T` and `b == false;`. B) in the specialization there is no `type` member alias. And thats the whole purpose of `std::enable_if`. When the condition is false then `std::enable_if< condition, T>::type` is a substitution failure, because the specialization has no `type`. When the `condition` is `true` then `std::enable_if<condition,T>::type` is just `T`.